# Do "safety cheques" really provide added security and reduce fraud?

Tags: canada, security, fraud, checking-account

I came across an article/advertorial, in print, describing the virtues of *safety cheques*.  Safety cheques are purported to be a good tool for fighting cheque fraud.  The features of the cheques include:

- A hologram,
- Microprinting and other high-resolution elements,
- Watermarks.

The gist of the article is that by using these (presumably more expensive) features on one's cheques, the incidence of cheque fraud can be reduced.

My questions are:

- Do these cheques actually make it any safer for people to use cheques?
- **Do bankers (or anybody else) check the hologram, microprinting, or other elements of a supposed safety cheque during the clearing process** to ensure it hasn't been tampered with or duplicated?

  (Isn't it up to the account owner to verify whether cheques that cleared were authentic or not?)
- Is one any more **liable** if one orders and uses only *regular* (non-safety) cheques and is then the victim of cheque fraud?
- Are there any studies that indicate a reduced incidence of fraud for safety cheques, whether in Canada or other countries?

Answer (score 1):

> Do bankers (or anybody else) check the hologram, microprinting, or
>   other elements of a supposed safety cheque during the clearing process
>   to ensure it hasn't been tampered with or duplicated?

I believe they do. When I deposited a check in a Chase branch, the cashier passed it through an UV light beam.

> (Isn't it up to the account owner to verify whether cheques that
>   cleared were authentic or not?)

The safety features would help you here as well. If you know that your checks should have it and the one cashed doesn't - it's something you can use to prove to the bank it was forged and recover your money.

> Is one any more liable if one orders and uses only regular
>   (non-safety) cheques and is then the victim of cheque fraud?

I don't think its a matter of liability, but I do think it makes it easier to prove that the fraudulent checks are in fact fraudulent.

> Are there any studies that indicate a reduced incidence of fraud for
>   safety cheques, whether in Canada or other countries?

Great question, would like to know the answer for that one.

Comment: I don't think its about reducing fraud attempts so much as detecting and preventing it from costing the bank or account holder due to the fraud.